# absolutely positioned picture covering text

Tags: html, css

I have a picture that i've positioned absolutely to use as a background. But it's covering up the content of the page.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style> 
  #pic1 
  { 
    position:absolute; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
  }

</style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1> hi there </h1>
    <h1> hi there </h1>
    <h1> hi there </h1>     
    <img id="pic1" src="1.jpg" width="100%" alt="picture">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you really want it to be a background image? If so, there are a lot better ways to do this... If you did want it to work with just an absolutely positioned image, you could set the z-index to -1 though.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the z-index css property of the image

The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.

An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order

how ever you can use another property on you body element to set background :
background-image:url('image url');

Answer (score 1):

Why not use background image placement?  This way you have less markup and more control over how you want the background to be displayed.  If you still want to place background in this way, then try `z-index: -1` and see if that works.

Overall, the way you are creating this page is less than optimal.  You are setting image width using attribute.  Why not get rid of img tag altogether and just roll with image placement using CSS.  Lots of stuff on the web that shows how to do it.